# Add and remove multiple classes to an element on scroll, reversing animation

Tags: jquery, css, css-animations

I'm animating a bounce in effect to an element once the user scrolls to a particular point of the page. I have this working by adding a class and then removing it at this point. However, I have another bounce out animation which is the reverse. I want to the element to bounce out when the user scrolls back up. So, I want to add the 'scrolled' and 'duration' classes when scrolled, and then when the user scrolls back, I want to add the 'duration' and 'not-scrolled' classes.

Here is a simple version:

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){
          if ($(window).scrollTop() > 200){
              $('.bounce-square').addClass( 'duration scrolled');
          }
          else{
            $('.bounce-square').removeClass( 'duration scrolled');
            //$('.bounce-square').addClass( 'duration not-scrolled');
          }
       });
```

```css
.bounce-square{
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 15%;
  left: 15%;
  opacity: 0;
}

.scrolled{
  opacity: 1;
  animation-name: bounceIn;
}

.not-scrolled{
  animation-name: bounceOut;
}

.duration{
  animation-duration: .75s;
}

@keyframes bounceIn {
  from, 20%, 40%, 60%, 80%, to {
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
  }

  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(.3, .3, .3);
    transform: scale3d(.3, .3, .3);
  }

  20% {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1.1);
    transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1.1);
  }

  40% {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(.9, .9, .9);
    transform: scale3d(.9, .9, .9);
  }

  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.03, 1.03, 1.03);
    transform: scale3d(1.03, 1.03, 1.03);
  }

  80% {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(.97, .97, .97);
    transform: scale3d(.97, .97, .97);
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  }
}

@keyframes bounceOut {
  20% {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(.9, .9, .9);
    transform: scale3d(.9, .9, .9);
  }

  50%, 55% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1.1);
    transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1.1);
  }

  to {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(.3, .3, .3);
    transform: scale3d(.3, .3, .3);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bounce-square"></div>
<p>Please scroll a little</p>
<div style="height: 3000px"></div>
```

I've commented out the one line of Javascript that I thought would work.

I've tried a mix of toggleclass and removing/adding classes at different points, but nothing is working the way I imagine.

I'd appreciate any help with this.

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/hbndag6L/1/

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Readdressing the adding and removing logic gets closer to the desired effect. From here you can tweak the css to enhance.

```js
var bounce = $('.bounce-square');
bounce.addClass('duration');

$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > 200) {
    bounce.removeClass('not-scrolled');
    bounce.addClass('scrolled');
  } else {
    if (bounce.hasClass('scrolled')) {
      bounce.removeClass('scrolled');
      bounce.addClass('not-scrolled');
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.bounce-square {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 15%;
  left: 15%;
  opacity: 0;
}
.scrolled {
  opacity: 1;
  animation-name: bounceIn;
}
.not-scrolled {
  animation-name: bounceOut;
}
.duration {
  animation-duration: .75s;
}
@keyframes bounceIn {
  from, 20%, 40%, 60%, 80%, to {
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
  }
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(.3, .3, .3);
    transform: scale3d(.3, .3, .3);
  }
  20% {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1.1);
    transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1.1);
  }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(.9, .9, .9);
    transform: scale3d(.9, .9, .9);
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.03, 1.03, 1.03);
    transform: scale3d(1.03, 1.03, 1.03);
  }
  80% {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(.97, .97, .97);
    transform: scale3d(.97, .97, .97);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  }
}
@keyframes bounceOut {
  20% {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(.9, .9, .9);
    transform: scale3d(.9, .9, .9);
  }
  50%,
  55% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1.1);
    transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1.1);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(.3, .3, .3);
    transform: scale3d(.3, .3, .3);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bounce-square"></div>
<p>Please scroll a little</p>
<div style="height: 3000px"></div>
```